# C++ random string values on declaration

Tags: c++, string

I have a problem when using string.

This is my C++ code:

```c++
string s;
s = "..\inputs\Meknes_ext1\REF_WV02_12SEP15_ext1";
```

The compilation was successfully done, but when debugging, the string `s` takes random values like "hûJ" at the first line and then the affectation don't change his  content.

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: It's possible it's escaping the character (\n for example is a new  line), replace \ with \\.

Comment: `The compilation was successfully done,`  There were no warnings about using illegal escape sequences?

Comment: no warning in compilation, and the problem still the same when I replace \ with \\ and even when I put any other string like s = "hello world"  it takes only 'o world'

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the escape character `\`, change this to `\\`:

```c++
s = "..\\inputs\\Meknes_ext1\\REF_WV02_12SEP15_ext1";
```

Comment: the problem still the same when I replace \ with \\ and even when I put any other string like s = "hello world" it takes only 'o world'. seems that the problem come from the declaration when a rondom value is attributed to the string and i don't know why

Answer (score 1):

you need to escape the `\` special character. Your string must be like that:

```
s = "..\\inputs\\Meknes_ext1\\REF_WV02_12SEP15_ext1";
```

Comment: the problem still the same when I replace \ with \\ and even when I put any other string like s = "hello world" it takes only 'o world'. seems that the problem come from the declaration when a rondom value is attributed to the string and i don't know why

Comment: random values seen at the add watch

Answer (score 0):

I find out that this problem occur only when debugging, in the execution, the string takes the right value, note that I'm using the RelWithDebInfo mode. the explanation of this was find in:  [Visual Studio: Garbled debug watch of std::string's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541951/visual-studio-garbled-debug-watch-of-stdstrings)